# Drupal 7 altering query in view

Tags: drupal, view, alter

I'm trying to alter a query in a view using mymodule_views_pre_execute and have used devel to find the sql query it is currently using, which is below:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid FROM node node LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date
 field_data_field_date ON node.nid = field_data_field_date.entity_id AND
 (field_data_field_date.entity_type = :views_join_condition_0 AND
 field_data_field_date.deleted     = :views_join_condition_1) 
 WHERE ((
 (DATE_FORMAT(field_data_field_date.field_date_value, '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i') > :node_date_filter) )AND
(( (node.status = :db_condition_placeholder_2) )))     
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I am then re-doing this using the following:

```
$query = db_select("node", "n");
            $query->addField("n", "nid");
            $query->leftJoin("{field_data_field_date}", "{field_data_field_date}",
            "n.nid = field_data_field_date.entity_id AND field_data_field_date.entity_type = 'node'
            AND field_data_field_date.deleted = '0'");

            $query->where("(DATE_FORMAT(field_data_field_date.field_date_value, '%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%i') > NOW())");
            $query->where("n.status = '1'");
```

I've had to replace :`views_join_condition_0` with '`node`', :`views_join_condition_1` with '`0`' and :`node_date_filter` to `NOW()` although i'm not sure if this is the correct way? If I leave :`views_join_condition_0`, :`views_join_condition_1` and :`node_date_filter` in though it doesn't work?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `hook_view_query_alter(&$view, &$query)`  instead.